# issue while importing from sqlserver into hive using apache sqoop?

Tags: sql-server, bash, hadoop, sqoop

When i run following sqoop command from **$SQOOP_HOME/bin** it works fine

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ip_address:port_number;database=database_name;username=sa;password=sa@Admin" --table $SQL_TABLE_NAME --hive-import --hive-home $HIVE_HOME --hive-table $HIVE_TABLE_NAME -m 1
```

But when i run the same command in a loop for different databases from bash script as follows

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do  
$DATABASE_NAME=$line

sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ip_address:port_number;database=$DATABASE_NAME;username=sa;password=sa@Admin" --table $SQL_TABLE_NAME --hive-import --hive-home $HIVE_HOME --hive-table $HIVE_TABLE_NAME -m 1  

done < "$1"
```

I am passing database names to my bash script in text file as parameter. My hive table is same  as i want to append data from all databases in one hive table only.

For first two-three databases it works fine after that it starts giving following errors

```
15/06/25 11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1435124207953_0033 failed with state FAILED due to:  

15/06/25 11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: The MapReduce job has already been retired. Performance  

15/06/25 11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: counters are unavailable. To get this information,  

15/06/25 11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: you will need to enable the completed job store on  

15/06/25 11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: the jobtracker with:  
11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase:mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.active = true  
11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.hours = 1  
15/06/25 11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: A jobtracker restart is required for these settings  
15/06/25 11:41:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: to take effect.  
15/06/25 11:41:06 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

I have already restarted my multi-node hadoop cluster by changing mapred-site.xml with above two said parametrs i.e

```
mapreduce.ImportJobBase:mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.active = true  
 mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.hours = 1
```

Still i am facing same problem. As i have just started learning sqoop any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We are facing this issue with Hue running sqoop via shell